# Error Message Mex file Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex

Has any one had before this error message :

**Undefined function or method 'name of function' for inputs arguments of type 'double'.**

I always have this error message when compiling a mex file. I have checked well the path, and it seems to be the right one.

This is my code, the mex file is `amortiss.c`

```
#include "mex.h"

/* The computational functions */
void arrayquotient(double input1, double input2, double output1)
{

   output1=input1/input2;

}


/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
/* variable declarations here */
    double input1;      /* input scalar 1 */
    double input2;       /* input scalar 2*/
    double output1;      /* output scalar 1 */   

/* code here */
    /* get the value of the scalar input1  */
   input1 = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

/* get the value of the scalar input2 */
   input2 = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);

/* get the value of the scalar input3 */
   input3 = mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);

/* create the output scalar1 */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(input1/input2);

/* get the value of the scalar output1 */
   output1 = mxGetScalar(plhs[0]);

/* call the computational routines */
arrayquotient(input1,input2,output1);
}
```

I added the path (command add path) to make sure the mex file `amortiss.c` exists. Then I created a .m file called `arrayquotient.m` in which I just wrote the declaration of my function :

`function c = arrayquotient(a,b)`

But, when compiling, another error message appears:

```
Error in ==> arrayquotient at 1
function c=arrayquotient(a,b)

??? Output argument "c" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"C:\Users\hp\Documents\MATLAB\codes_Rihab\arrayquotient.m>arrayquotient".
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually [compiling the MEX](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html)? Usually you would get "Undefined function etc." if you hadn't actually compiled the function.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is the function you are trying to write called `amortiss` or `arrayquotient`?  Unless you compile with the correct flags, your compiled mex file will be `amortiss`.  Please report the result of `which arrayquotient -all` and `which amortiss -all`.

Comment: The assignment to parameter `output1` in `arrayquotient` does not change the different variable `output1` in `mexFunction`.  If `output1` in `mexFunction` were assigned, that alone would not change the value in `plhs[0]`.  You should check `nrhs` to avoid crashing Matlab on bad inputs.

Comment: Thank you all for responding.My mex file is"amortiss.c" and the function is  called "arrayquotient".I've compiled the Mex file using the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express compiler but once I get in the repetoire I don't find the " .mexw32" file neither of the "arrayquotient" function nor of the "amortiss.c" file. Do you think that this is the problem ? and what can I do now ? please I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `amortiss.c` is a c-file and CANNOT be executed as-is by Matlab.
The file, `arrayquotient.m`, you created is an empty function that does not assign value to its output `c`.

What you need to do is to **mex** the c-file `amortiss.c` to create a mex file `amortiss.mexw32` (the extension differs according to your architecture. Use `mexext` to find out the extension you should be looking for).

In matlab, setup your mex compiler:

```
>> mex -setup
```

You will be instructed to choose from compilers installe don your machine and recognized by Matlab.

Once you setup your mex compiler you can go on and mex the c-file

```
>> mex -O -largeArrayDims amortiss.c
```

Then you'll have a mex-file `amortiss.mexXXX` (with 'XXX' depending on your architecture).
You can cll the function like any other function

```
>> c = amortiss( a, b );
```

Comment: @ Shai,thank you for responding.I've done what you said and I've chosen the Compiler:Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express.I've also deleted the M file "arrayquotient.m" Then here is what I typed: mex amortiss.c
>> c =2.;
>> b = 3.;
>> d = arrayquotient(c,b)
??? Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Users\hp\Documents\MATLAB\arrayquotient.mexw32': C:\Users\hp\Documents\MATLAB\arrayquotient.mexw32 n’est
pas une application Win32 valide.  what should I do now ??? I appreciate your help !!

Comment: what is the output of `>> mexext`?

Comment: when I type >> mexext  it gives me: mexw32

Comment: You should remove `arrayquotient.mex32` and run `>> c = amortiss( a, b );`

Comment: :I've removed arrayquotient.mex32 and I typed: 
>> mex amortiss.c        %% my mex file
>> a =2.;>> b=3.;
>> c = arrayquotient(a,b)  %% my function
??? Undefined function or method 'arrayquotient' for input arguments of type 'double'. %% the error message.I'm not sure but I think the function and the mexfile should have the same name so that when I compile the file .c,the function is automaticlly compiled.does it make sence?do you have any other explanation?A second question:Is it possible to have many mexFunctions in the same mex file(each one is associated with a function)?Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rarepearl run `>> c = amortiss( a, b );` the name of the function is the **SAME** as the c-file name.

Comment: @Rarepearl you can only have one `mexFunction` in each c-file.

Comment: I changed the function's name and it worked well.It is just that simple.Anyway thank you very much for your precious help.At the moment, it is working well. Thanks a lot for all your advice and help.

Comment: I have one last question: I want to connect the "amortiss.c" I have to the CLIPS Expert System (.clp). Do you know any way to do this ? Or at least how to connect an .m function to the CLIPS Expert System ?According to the Clips user guide I should define external function called user-defined function. The problem is that this function is a CLIPS function written in C ..so I don't see how it helps me connect my "amortiss.c" to CLIPS. Please I need your help again. I appreciate all your suggestion and advice.

Comment: @Rarepearl i am not familiar with CLIPS. you can accept (and up vote?) this answer, and post your comment as a new question (so other people may view it as well). You may provide a link to this question from your new question to show context.

Comment: I accepted your answer and up voted it . Thank you very much for all your help. (I wanted to up vote again but it tells me "vote up requires 15 reputation" )

Comment: @Rarepearl Thank you! Feel free to post your CLIPS question, maybe there are other prople out there that can help you.